# Why won't binary reader read contents of *.wav

Tags: c#

I cannot figure out why I'm getting zero's after reading the supposed contents of a *.wav file.

Link to images of output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4n5h.jpg

```
using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(File.Open("test.wav", FileMode.Open))) {

            // Read the wave file header from the buffer. 

            int chunkID = reader.ReadInt32 ();          print (chunkID);
            int fileSize = reader.ReadInt32();          print (fileSize);
            int riffType = reader.ReadInt32();          print (riffType);
            int fmtID = reader.ReadInt32();             print (fmtID);
            int fmtSize = reader.ReadInt32();           print (fmtSize);
            int fmtCode = reader.ReadInt16();           print (fmtCode);
            int channels = reader.ReadInt16();          print (channels);
            int sampleRate = reader.ReadInt32();        print (sampleRate);
            int fmtAvgBPS = reader.ReadInt32();         print (fmtAvgBPS);
            int fmtBlockAlign = reader.ReadInt16();     print (fmtBlockAlign);
            int bitDepth = reader.ReadInt16();          print (bitDepth);

            int dataID = reader.ReadInt32();            print (dataID);
            int dataSize = reader.ReadInt32();          print (dataSize);

            byteArray = reader.ReadBytes(dataSize);

            // After this you have to split that byte array for each channel (Left,Right)
            // Wav supports many channels, so you have to read channel from header
        }
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: What is your `print` function?

Comment: Problems with Endian? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Comment: You should post the output in the question instead of linking an image.  Also have you tried looking at the wav file in a hex editor to verify your results?

Comment: The code itself looks OK and works on dummy `.wav` file, so you need to post the actual `test.wav` which I suspect is the culprit here.

Comment: @juharr I have not tried looking at the file in a hex editor.  Do you have a recommendation for one? Does Notepad++ do that?

Comment: @rbm Sure!  Here's the file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/m93s0aj13ld6k9e/test.wav?dl=0

Comment: I believe there is a plugin for NotePad++.

Comment: So I've completely circumvented the issue with the following code.  I was trying to load a *.wav file a completely tedious way, but what I was missing before was adding "file://" into the string of the filename.  Thank you so much for your help!  I greatly appreciate it!

www = new WWW ("file://test.wav");
  AudioClip myAudioClip = www.audioClip;
  while (myAudioClip.loadState != AudioDataLoadState.Loaded) {
   print ("still in loop");
   yield return www;
  }

  GetComponent<AudioSource> ().clip = myAudioClip;
  GetComponent<AudioSource> ().Play ();

Answer (score 0):

See this definition of the WAV header :

http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/

you will see that after BitsPerSample (bitDepth) there are optional values before you get to the "data" header & data size.

If it is not a PCM format - you need to read these too or just search for "data" after bitDepth.

On the file I have just checked - the first value is an int16 specifying the number of int16s following - in this particular case 12, so reading an additional 24 bytes brings me to the "data" header.

```
    // Read the wave file header from the buffer. 
    int chunkID = reader.ReadInt32();    // ASCII string = "RIFF"
    print(chunkID);
    int fileSize = reader.ReadInt32();
    print(fileSize);
    int riffType = reader.ReadInt32();   // ASCII string "WAVE"
    print(riffType);
    int fmtID = reader.ReadInt32();      // ASCII string "fmt "
    print(fmtID);
    int fmtSize = reader.ReadInt32();    // 16 = PCM (actually specifies size of data of this section)
    print(fmtSize);
    short fmtCode = reader.ReadInt16();
    print(fmtCode);
    short channels = reader.ReadInt16();
    print(channels);
    int sampleRate = reader.ReadInt32();
    print(sampleRate);
    int fmtAvgBPS = reader.ReadInt32();
    print(fmtAvgBPS);
    short fmtBlockAlign = reader.ReadInt16();
    print(fmtBlockAlign);
    short bitDepth = reader.ReadInt16();
    print(bitDepth);

    short[] extraPars = null;
    if (fmtSize != 16)
    {
      short NoOfEPs = reader.ReadInt16();
      extraPars = new short[NoOfEPs];
      for (int i=0;i<NoOfEPs;i++)
        extraPars[i] = reader.ReadInt16();;
    }

    int dataID = reader.ReadInt32();    // ASCII string = "data"
    print(dataID);
    int dataSize = reader.ReadInt32();
    print(dataSize);

    byte [] byteArray = new byte[dataSize];
    byteArray = reader.ReadBytes(dataSize);
```